# Same style repeating for sublinks

Tags: css, class, html-lists, repeat

I'm making a navigation bar. [Here's the reference link](http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/437/CSS3-only-horizontal-drop-line-tab-menu)

The problem is the style I've applied for Main Tabs is repeating for Sub Links as well. I've created separate class for the sub links("nav2"). It works fine in Chrome & Mozilla Firefox, but not able to solve this issue in IE. Please Help, Its bit urgent.

Here's my code

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
<ul id="nav">
<li><a href="#">Tab1</a>
<ul id="nav2">
<li><a href="#">Menu 1 Submenu item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu 1 Submenu item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Menu 1 Submenu item 3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="#">Tab2</a>
<ul id="nav2">
<li><a href="#">Sub Link for tab 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Some other link</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Some othe rlink</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="#">Tab3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Tab4</a></li>

</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Here's the css

CSS:

```
#menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  clear: both;
}

ul#nav {
float: left;
width:100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}

ul#nav li {
 display: inline;
}

ul#nav li a {
  float: left;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
font-weight:bold;
line-height: 35px;
color: #7e764c;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #ffffff;
margin:0 4px 0 0;
padding: 0 15px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
background: #fff3b3;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fffce9', endColorstr='#fff3b3');
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 70%, from(#fffce9), to(#fff3b3));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fffce9, #fff3b3 70%);
background: linear-gradient(#fffce9, #fff3b3 70%);
-pie-background: linear-gradient(#fffce9, #fff3b3 70%);
behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}

ul#nav .current a, ul#nav li:hover > a  {
color: #353535;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #ffe8a1;
background: #fecf3a;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px; 
}

ul#nav  ul {
display: none;
}

ul#nav2 li a {
background:none;
}

ul#nav li:hover > ul {
position: absolute;
display: block;
width: 100%;
height: 35px;
position: absolute;
margin: 35px 0 0 0;
background-color:#fecf3a;
border-bottom:1px solid #c3aa6f;
}

ul#nav li:hover > ul li {
float: left;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
font-weight:normal;
line-height: 35px;
color: #86610b;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 0;
background:url(../img/line1.jpg) no-repeat right 15px;
}

ul#nav li:hover > ul li a {
float: left;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size:11px;
font-weight:normal;
line-height: 35px;
color: #86610b;
text-decoration: none;
margin: 0;
background:url(../img/arrow-btm2.png) no-repeat center 28px;
}

ul#nav li:hover > ul li a:hover {
color: #86610b;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: none;
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try changing the `ul#nav2 li a` to `#nav ul li a`

Comment: @Pos5e5s3dFr3ak, I tried changing it, but still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: You have not added a class to the submenus. You have added the id "nav2" and ids should be unique. You should change this to class="nav2" and use .nav2 instead of #nav2 in your css to target that.

There are two good ways to solve this.

1)

Create classes for the toplevel items. Something like:

```
<ul id="nav"> 
    <li class="navLevel1"><a href="#">Tab1</a>
```

And then you change *ul#nav li* to *.navLevel1* and *ul#nav li a* to *.navLevel1 > a* in your css.

2)

Change *ul#nav li* to *#nav > li* and *#nav li a* to *#nav > li > a* in your css

Note:
I used the child selector(>) which means you only select direct children of the element instead of descendants.

Comment: Thanks, I used your 2nd Option, its not repeating in IE now, But the styling on Hover is not displaying properly. I changed ul#nav li:hover > ul  to  #nav > li:hover > ul & so on for all the Hover classes. Am I doing something wrong

Comment: Thanks a lot its done, just had to do some padding changes in the Hover class. Can't thank you enough. I've marked your answer as the correct one

Comment: Sorry to ask you this question again. Maybe that day I din't notice. Now there is another problem in IE. It doesn't highlight the tab when I mouseover it. Also it doesn't display Rounded corners for the tabs. I think its because of the background Image I'm using for the little arrow below the sublinks. Can u help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also is there a way I can make the first tab open by default.

Comment: Hello, there is some changes in the design now, & we don't need gradient in the tabs now. So when I removed the gradient effect the tabs are highlighting in IE. So The problem of highlighting the tabs is solved now. Can you help me with with the rounded corners issue & opening the first tab by default. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you open two new questions for that? That way other people with the same problem will have it easier to find your question and the answer. You can copy the links here and I will take a look.

Comment: Sure, but if I post new question, do I have to post the html & css again. Sorry for asking this but I'am not very used to forums. This is first time m using a forum.

Comment: I've sorted out the issue of rounded corners in IE. Now the only issue is opening the first subtabs by default. I've posted new question for this. Here's the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12387554/how-to-make-sub-tabs-open-by-default